# Flutter Semi circle progress bar with minor arc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I want to draw a widget like the one below (with semi-circle and minor arc of it):
[image]

I found libraries like [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) but I want just a minor arc of the circle not half of it.

I tried this code but it's not good looking:

```dart
Transform.scale(
      scaleX: 2,
      child: SleekCircularSlider(appearance: CircularSliderAppearance()),
    )
```

[image]

Is there a way to do it better without doing tricks like using a stack and moving extra space outside the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Arc shape progress bar by using this new package:

https://pub.dev/packages/arc_progress_bar_new

You just call it like this, and adjust the arc parameters:

```js
  ArcProgressBar(
    percentage: _progressPercentage,
    arcThickness: 5,
    innerPadding: 16,
    animateFromLastPercent: true,
    handleSize: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
    foregroundColor: Colors.black
    )
```